# Status request 404 for Json data in wp8.1

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

In my application I passed a request api url and when I try to open the link it shows the Json data in the browser. But when I try to deserialize the Json data I got 404 status.

```
 Uri geocodeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4271,078.4466&radius=500&type=petrol_bunk&key=MyKey"));

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(geocodeRequest);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode==true)
        {
```

When I open this [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4271,078.4466&radius=500&type=petrol_bunk&key=AIzaSyCguNRWmAkk_Vctf0bePWiY1rIjM399Loo) I can see the Json data but when I try this link in my code the status shows 404 error(No data resources). Also please check this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WbYVJblzMoYVdfbWQ1aTdkb2M/view?usp=sharing) for the image displayed while debugging my project

Comment: Did you try to read using 
 System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage tResponse = tClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, content).Result;
string result = tResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: With out success response 200 how can we read the result..??

Answer (score 0):

It should be about the refuse from the server.
The different between using HttpClient & Web browser to browse website is
"You don't have the same header and method"

Let's try adding other header parameters like Agent,Content-type, Content-length

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage() {
                                        RequestUri = new Uri("http://www.someURI.com"),
                                        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                                        ...........
                                    };

request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain")); }
```

Comment: Before two days the same code in the question given the status result as 200 and got the results. But when I try to execute it today it is showing 404 error

Comment: did you try adapt my code ?
URI : without string.Format and set to GET.
If it still return error, try adding agent.