# Check the Json response code and find the error in win phn 8.1

Tags: c#, json, http, windows-phone-8.1

Before two days I done a project with help of Json data api. In that app I successfully got the result in the Json format. By de serializing the data I used it in my application. I updated that project to github. And today when I reopen my project and tried to execute it. The Http response status message is 404(i.e no data). But when I copy and paste the url in browser it shows the Json data. But in my code I cannot deserialize the data.

What is the issue with Http response and request.

This is the duplicate question [of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340212/status-request-404-for-json-data-in-wp8-1) as I didn't get the targeted answer am posting my question again. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download fiddler, configure your phone to see request in it and see what exactly requests you are sending and what it shoudl be. Maybe there is a difference in headers?